# Voltage output on current regulator drops when I power ammeter via same power supply as circuit

Tags: power-supply, current-measurement, current-limiting

I am running this cheap ammeter on a NPN transistor based current limiter. When I attempt to power the ammeter via the same power supply as the current limiter, the voltage across the current limiter drops and I get a slight current through the ammeter. When I use an external 12 volt supply the system begins to behave normally, and I get zero current through the ammeter and around 12 volts across the current limiter when it is an open circuit (R_load = inf.) I imagine the cheap ammeter allows some current to flow through it when it is grounded to the same circuit.

[image: cheap ammeter]

[image: schematic]

Comment: Do you have a datasheet for this ammeter? If so, what does it say about isolation between its power supply and sense input?

Comment: This is not an active current limiter circuit. Q2 and R1 should be in opposite locations with some other changes

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_limiting These are different current limiters.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I accidentally implemented the version for PNP transistors with NPN transistors. thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem. The cheap ammeter only works when it is on the ground side of the circuit. I tried connecting it before the load and that is why it did not work. I think the ground for the current sensing and power leads on the ammeter must be common or something like that.